# RavenDB IDocumentStoreListener BeforeStore return false entity still saved

Tags: ravendb

According to [RavenDB document](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/client-side-listeners), when `BeforeStore()` returns `false`, the entity instance should not updated.

> Whatever the entity instance was modified and requires us re-serialize it.
>   Returning true would force re-serialization of the entity, returning false would 
>   mean that any changes to the entityInstance would be ignored in the current SaveChanges call.

I have tested return both `true` and `false`, no difference. Return `false` won't stop saving the entity to database.

Here is my listener:

```
public bool BeforeStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata, RavenJObject original)
{
    if (entityInstance is Person)
    {
        var person = (Person)entityInstance;
        person.Firstname = "Tom"; // used be John
        return false;
    }
}
```

It turns out the person's first name is changed to "Tom" even it returns false.
Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please re-read the documentation. The return value just says whether **you** have changed the document in your `IDocumentStoreListener`.

Comment: @Tom, in my example above, if BeforeStore() return false, the changes in the listener will be discarded, the person's first name should be "John". but it has been changed to "Tom".

Comment: I cannot replicate what you are saying. See my [small test app](https://gist.github.com/thoemmi/8123604): As long as `BeforeStore` returns `false`, the person's name isn't changed.

Comment: @Tom, your example works fine with me too. How come it does not work the way it suppose to be in my other MVC 4 project. This project has large scale, with factories, repositories, unitOfWork pattern and agatha as the service layer. Anything i can check why it still persist change in IDocumentStorelistener even it returns false? Thanks.

Comment: The question is why do you change the document and still return `false`? I don't know the exact code, but the return value may just be a hint for RavenDB.

Comment: That's a good question. Actually I happen to notice it does not make any difference in my system. The store listener comes handy when i need to set the system read only mode during upgrade. In this case, i throw an exception instead of return false.